#  StringCollection changes  on Settings.Default.Reload()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-2.0

In my app `Settings.Default.test` is a `StringCollection`. I don't understand why this code

```
    StringCollection col = new StringCollection();
    col.Add("1\r\n2\r\n");
    Settings.Default.test = col;
    Settings.Default.Save();
    Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Changes my text `1\r\n2\r\n` to `1\n2\n` on Reload. 
Is it default behavior or what? 
How to restore multiline text in my textbox on restart of my application?

Comment: Could have something to do with serialization.

Answer (score 1):

When the data is saved to the user.config settings it will look like this:
(c:\users[username]\appdata\local[appname]..\user.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <EmptyObjects.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <string>1
2
</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>
                </value>
            </setting>
        </EmptyObjects.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

The data is serialized to XML then deserialized to string(s). If you need to preserve the information you can:

- Use tags like `<br>` to replace \r and after deserialize replace the `<br>` with \r..
- Or implement your own serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1(v=vs.80).aspx